# Gradient Checkpointing returning values

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have a checkpoint callback function (i.e, custom_dec) that returns a Tensor, and a dictionary. But it seems like this function does not return dictionaries (or other data types), but only tensors. What is the workaround to this, as the module that I want to checkpoint is returning a tensor, plus a data type as dictionary:

```
def custom_dec(self, module):
        def custom_forward(*inputs):
            output = module(inputs[0], inputs[1],
                            encoder_attn_mask=inputs[2],
                            decoder_padding_mask=inputs[3],
                            layer_state=inputs[4],
                            causal_mask=inputs[5],
                            output_attentions=inputs[6],
                            )
            # output[2] is a python dictionary
            return output[0], output[2]
```

The following is the checkpoint call:

```
x, layer_past = \
                checkpoint.checkpoint(
                    self.custom_dec(decoder_layer),
                    x,
                    encoder_hidden_states,
                    encoder_padding_mask,
                    decoder_padding_mask,
                    layer_state,
                    decoder_causal_mask,
                    output_attentions,
                )
```

The error:

> TypeError: CheckpointFunctionBackward.forward: expected Variable (got
> dictionary) for return value 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar situation was discussed [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pass-none-to-gradient-checkpointing/99389/3?u=gautam_sreekumar).

What you can do is to convert the dictionary into some tensor form. I faced an error where it was caused by an input list which is not accepted by `torch.utils.checkpoint`. My solution was to pass the tensors in the list as independent tensors and form a list out of them in `custom_forward`.

I don't know the form of your dictionary (e.g. if every key will always have a value), but you can come up with a Dictionary-Tensor inter-change scheme that works for your dictionary.